# traveling salesman without u-turn v.net.salesman grass

Tags: grass-gis, travelling-salesman

I want to compute a traveling salesman path with GRASS GIS 7.2.1 which avoids u-turns.

I made a network with v.net connect.
I made a turntable using this network.
I updated layer 3 of the turntable with costs=-1 where angle>3.14 (+/-180deg).
It looks to be ok because ln_from and ln_to are the same with this query.

I try v.net.salesman using the turntable (layer 1 to 4) but the result is bad. U-turns are still present and there's a lot of superimposed lines in the result.